# Why is it that after I compress a string, save it to SQL Server, then retrieve it, the data looks different?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, compression

I have an XML Audit log which is represented by a string in my c# code. I wanted to save this to my database as bytes to reduce the size of a table. When I use my code to compress/decompress the string and show it in C#, the audit log shows correctly. However if I compress --> save to the database-->decompress, all I get is a blank string.

My code for compressing/decompressing:

```
private static byte[] ZipFile(string auditLog) {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(auditLog);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
                //msi.CopyTo(gs);
                CopyTo(msi, gs);
            }

            return mso.ToArray();
        }
}

private static string UnzipFile(byte[] bytes) {
        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
                //gs.CopyTo(mso);
                CopyTo(gs, mso);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
}
```

My code for retrieving from the database:

```
private void populateFromCursor(DbReader cursor, Job value) {
    value.id = (int)(cursor.GetInt64(0));
    value.functionId = cursor.GetString(1);
    byte[] binaryAuditLog = (byte[]) cursor.GetDbValue(2);
    string auditLog = UnzipFile(binaryAuditLog);
    value.auditLog = auditLog;
}
```

In my table the column type is set as `varbinary`.

Comment: You're calling a method named `UnzipFile` but have shown two methods named `CompressFile`, can you post the correct code?

Comment: Sorry, I'd renamed the methods. Code updated

Comment: Find out where in the chain the data was corrupted. What came back from the DB when reading? The reason for why the output is empty will be obvious when using the debugger.

Comment: When it comes back from the DB I get byte[1] but that doesn't make it obvious as to where the data loss is coming from?

Comment: Or rather, it makes it clear that the problem lies in saving to the DB and extracting, but it doesn't seem to give an indicator as to why

Comment: What are the `CopyTo()` calls? And why are the lines above them commented out, they seem the right calls to use?

Comment: It seems like a homebrew version of Stream.CopyTo.

Comment: Now we know that decompression is not an issue. Query the database using select * from to see if the data is corrupt. Investigate! I already showed you how. Stop guessing.

Comment: You didn't show me anything. All you've stated is to look in the debugger, which I've already looked through. And yes I've already queried the database and it seems that the values are being saved there as binary values.

Comment: So saving does not truncate but reading truncates. Makes it seem like the reading code from the database is broken. Do you agree? So what's the length of binaryAuditLog after reading it? Should be like 0 or 1.